# Dictionaries for fast lookup of KeyString

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I know this can probably be achieved all at once, but anyway it is complicated enough for me, since it's my first project :))

```
public class Definitions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int smallId { get; set; }
}


    public static void getDefinitions()
    {
        var files = (from name in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Folder)
                     select new Definitions
                     {
                         Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name),
                           Id = File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).First()
                                }).ToArray();


        //LOOP THROUGH DATABASE ++++++++++
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((files[i].Id) == idFromDatabase)
            {
                files[i].smallId = smallIdFromDatabase;
            }
        //LOOP THROUGH DATABASE ++++++++++


        //+++++++++++++ Dictionary CREATE++++++++++++++++
        Dictionary<string, int> _dict =
        new Dictionary<string, int>();

        foreach (Definitions item in files)
        {
            _dict.Add(item.Name,item.smallId);
        }
        //+++++++++++++ Dictionary CREATE++++++++++++++++

    return _dict;
    }
```

All the above CODE needs to be executed just ONCE!!
I do not need the Definitions class anymore or anything else.
I just need that DICTIONARY everywhere.

Then I want a simple check method for the id:

```
        public static string GetID(string word)
        {
            // ++++++Dictionary check +++++++
            string result;
            if (_dict.TryGetValue(word, out result))
            {
            return result;
            }
            else
            {
            return null;
            }
            }
```

Right now I only managed to return the dictionary to the main, and perform the lookup directly there.

(And of course to give that _DICT to that lookup function, every-time I do that lookup is probably very stupid)

The thing to do that, as I suspect, is to put everything in a static class, I already tried according to my basic knowledge , but something is always missing, jiggling lines all over the place. :))

EDITED VERSION according to answer++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace Testbase
{
public class Definitions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int smallId { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        _dict=GetDefinitions();
        string teststring = "StringToTest";
        Console.WriteLine(GetID(teststring));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    private static Dictionary<string, int> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    public static Dictionary<string, int> getDefinitions()
    {
    if (_dict.Count >= 0) return _dict;
        var files = (from name in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Settings.Folder)
                     select new Definitions
                     {
                         Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name),
                         Id = File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).First().Replace("</ID>", "").Replace("<ID>", "").Trim()
                     }).ToArray();
        //++++++++++++++++++ Loop trough databse ++++++++++++++++++++++++
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((files[i].Id) == idFromDatabase)
            {
                files[i].smallId = smallIdFromDatabase;
            }
        }
        //++++++++++++++++++ Loop trough databse ++++++++++++++++++++++++

        foreach (Definitions item in files)
        {
            _dict.Add(item.Name, item.smallId);
        }

        return _dict;
    }

    public static int GetID(string word)
    {
        int outp;
        if (_dict.TryGetValue(word, out outp))
        {
            return outp;
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
}
```

The Problem is it only works if I create a new Dictionary in the method GetID:

```
    public static int GetID(string word)
    {
```

But that can't be good, since I need that lookup very often

SOLVED #######################################
Of course I need _dict=getDefinitions(); on TOP of main.
Then I can call GETID everywhere, without creating a new DICT Object every time
Or at least that's what I think....
Big Thank YOU for the help

Great Forum !!!!!

Comment: If you want help with the errors in your static class code you need to actually show us the code and copy and paste the text of the errors from the error log in to your question. Also a custom [`class DefinationLookup : KeyedCollection<string, Definitions>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438(v=vs.110).aspx) might be a better data structure to use if you ever care about getting both `Id` and `smallId`.

Comment: The code so far works if I have everything in one method,...or if I return the _dict to main and access it there. But I have no clue how to realize that dictionary is available everywhere. And no I don't need ID only Name+smallID..the problem is to setup these class-stuff correct,...inside methods I am quiet comfortable. I read many tuts, but its diff to get in my  head:

Comment: thx Bob....but I wanna start simple first....My problem are still classes and where everything belongs in the code  `class DefinationLookup : KeyedCollection<string, Definitions>`  sounds good, but above was already hard enough, but I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here my changes to your code:

1) I changed the signature of `getDefinitions()` from void to Dictionary.

2) Declared a private field `_dict` that will hold your dictionary values at class level instead of variable in your method.

3) The private field is static.

4) I do a simple check at the beginning of `getDefinitions()` method to check if the field `_dict` is populated, then use it. Otherwise go and read files.

```
public class Definitions
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int smallId { get; set; }
}
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
    }
    // DECLARE THE DICTIONARY AT CLASS LEVEL.
    private static Dictionary<string, int> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

    // int idFromDatabase;
    // int smallIdFromDatabase;
    public static Dictionary<string, int> getDefinitions()
    {
        // RETURN DICTIONARY IF WE HAVE VALUE. DON'T NEED TO GET FILES!
        if (_dict.Count >= 0) return _dict;
        var files = (from name in Directory.EnumerateFiles(Folder)
            select new Definitions
            {
                Name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(name),
                Id = File.ReadLines(name).Skip(2).First()
            }).ToArray();


        //LOOP THROUGH DATABASE ++++++++++
        for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
        {
            if ((files[i].Id) == idFromDatabase)
            {
                files[i].smallId = smallIdFromDatabase;
            }
            //LOOP THROUGH DATABASE ++++++++++


            //+++++++++++++ Dictionary CREATE++++++++++++++++        

            foreach (Definitions item in files)
            {
                _dict.Add(item.Name, item.smallId);
            }
            //+++++++++++++ Dictionary CREATE++++++++++++++++   
            return _dict;
        }
    }

    public static int GetID(string word)
    {
        // ++++++Dictionary check +++++++
        int result;
        if (_dict.TryGetValue(word, out result))
        {
            return result;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Code-only answers aren't very helpful. How does this answer the question? What does this code do? Does it even run? I'd expect `File.ReadLines` to fail if you pass a filename without its extension

Comment: How does it solve the problem? Explain in the answer, don't expect people to try and guess from the code.

Comment: There are many issues with this answer. For one, the `ToDictionary` method can generate a Dictionary in one call. The last section isn't needed. Second, why not put a `where` section in the LINQ query and avoid the loop? Looking at the code, it seems that the only difference is declaring static fields? How does that help?

Comment: 1) The issues you found are not what he is asking!!! 2) He was complaining `getDefinitions()` is getting called everytime where it doesnt need to.  and this is his problem. 3) My changes are: A) declaring a field on class level, b) change the method signature, c) Add a check on new introduce field to check if it is populate; then return it and DON'T read files. READ his question and my answer and pay attention to details before giving advice.

Comment: Post the explanation in the answer. Don't expect people to go over all comments to understand the code. Comments can and *do* get deleted without warning

Comment: The code read itself!. And It is mean from you to votedown. You weren't able to understand his question and you weren't able to understand my answer!. So YOU are the one who has problem.

Comment: I suggest you chekc [How to write a good answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and [Is there any benefit to allowing code-only answers while blocking code-only questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/148272/is-there-any-benefit-to-allowing-code-only-answers-while-blocking-code-only-ques) among others. The community consensus is that code-only answers are low quality and should be deleted. I didn't flag the answer btw

Comment: At quick glance that answer helps me a lot.                                                private static Dictionary<string, int> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

public static Dictionary<string, int> getDefinitions()     when I do it like that can I put the _dict.TryGetValue(word, out result))-Function directly in my class? I will try to make it work now... thank you all so far

Comment: If `GetID()` method is in same class of the field `_dict`; then yes you can.

Comment: I don't really need to call getDefinitions() more than once.. but alot of GetID() calls....does getDefinitions() get to called more than once? and I am still lost to what put exactly where,....now everything is jiggled everywhere...lol...still trying   I cannot put code in here :((

Comment: `getDefinition()` will get called everytime, but it won't pass this line everytime `if(_dict.Count >= 0) return _dict;`. Just once.

Comment: 'class Program
    {
        private static Dictionary<string, int> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>();

        public static Dictionary<string, int> getDefinitions()
        {if(_dict.Count >= 0) return _dict;..........                                                    'and where to put 'GETID' now?..where is the field _dict?...it works only if I put 'Dictionary<string, int> _dict = getDefinitions();' INTO the 'GETID 'method,......but that can'T be right,. since I will need GETID really often....and I don't wanna create always a new Dictionary

Comment: `'class Program { private static Dictionary<string, int> _dict = new Dictionary<string, int>(); public static Dictionary<string, int> getDefinitions() {if(_dict.Count >= 0) return _dict;`

Comment: Wow still breaking my head now....I updated my question with your answer.....still only working if I create a new _dict EVERYTIME I call the method GETID

Comment: Of course I also tried to create the object once in main, but also doesn't work...

Comment: @Tetragrammaton i don't see this in your updated code: `if (_dict.Count >= 0) return _dict;`

Comment: yeah I know,...but at the moment I don't care to much if I go through that again and again...I will do that quickly anyway...thats not the issue(I think)             ....if I add:  `_dict = getDefinitions();`  I can at least use GETID in the main,...but not in other functions...I thought that _dict is now global/static?

Comment: OK thx you very much for your help...reallly awesome its works everywhere now,...the _dict = getDefinitions(); ON TOP of main was the key....lol.....I though that I don't need that, since I thought that static function is called anyway when the code needs it.